# ./Telegram:error while loading shared libraries

Tags: x11, libraries

Does anyone know this error?

```
tar -x -v -f tsetup.0.10.19.tar.xz
telegram/
telegram/updater
telegram/telegram

cd Telegram

./Telegram

./Telegram:error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: can not open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Reading the [installation guide for telegram](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/master/doc/building-cmake.md) would help tremendously. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @roaima These instructions are for those who want to compile from source. And yes, world would be better if they provided instructions for installing the precompiled package, properly referenced on the site where the executable is distributed (https://desktop.telegram.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Executables often depend on external pieces of software, called *shared libraries* (actually, libraries are executables as well). In order to run an executable, the *dynamic linker* needs to find all dependent libraries and load them. If it fails to do so, it prints an error message similar to the one you provided and gives up on loading the executable.

One can review all the libraries the executable depends on by issuing

```
ldd Telegram
```

In your case then, the message says that the linker cannot find the library `libX11-xcb.so.1`, presumably because it is not installed. This particular name is used by the library [`XCB`](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/).

To avoid the hassle associated with manual caring about library dependencies, people often use some kind of *package management system* for the task of installing software.

Answer (score 1):

libX11-xcb appears to be missing.  It's provided by RPM libX11 : see [rpmfind.net query](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libX11-xcb.so.1)

Install that RPM and retry.